# How to feed RFIN pin of HCS500?

Tags: rf, integrated-circuit, microchip

I am trying to make a prototype receiver based on [HCS500](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40153c.pdf) Keeloq decoder IC. However, I'm not sure what to feed with RFIN pin? Should I just put antenna or data from standard ASK/OOK decoder, which gives data bits already demodulated? Datasheet doesn't tell much about that part, so if anyone know how to deal with input part or got reference schematics for it I would appreciate it.

Comment: Hi, look for si4010 if is suitable for you project requirements.

Comment: @fabio thanks but I still don't know what kind of input `HCS500` requires...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this in the data sheet you linked to: -

[image]

You need a pukka radio receiver with data demodulator to feed the pin (not an antenna). It's a digital input i.e. logic.

Comment: so [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/RF-OOK-Remote-Modules-Control-Transceiver-RX-TX-ASK-modules-AM-Modules-433MHZ-/280909354931?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item41678097b3) kind of RF receiver which gives demodulated digital output(series of pulses) should do the job?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so BUT I could easily be wrong. I would imagine that the receiver you linked to wasn't receiving a valid transmission, it would be producing random data on it's output and this would likely be a problem for the HCS500. I think you need to speak with MicroChip about it or hope someone on EE has direct knowledge. I was just answering the "antenna" part of your question.

Comment: Thanks indeed. Hope someone can give me specific receiver recommendation for HCS500.

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be input to binary code in manchester format. With HCS201/301 is possible test this.

Edit:

Like this:

[image]

Comment: Having HCS301 how can I test this? If it's binary code, why pin named RF?

Comment: HCS301/201 is the counterpart of a decoder. It encodes. Maybe your car alarm keychain is one HCS201.

Comment: Yes, I know `HCS301/200/201` are counterparts, but how they can determine what kind is RFIN.

Comment: If HCS500 recognize the information of HCS301/200/201 - with the programmed keys before, of course - this pin is a logic/digital data input as we suspect.

Comment: Do you mean connect RF out pin of HCS301 to RFIN pin of HCS500? :)

Comment: No! HCS301->TX(Colppits)->Antenna (ETHER) Antenna->RF.Receiver.Module(SuperRegenerative)->DataOutPut.Digital->HCS500.

Comment: Well.... maybe HCS301.Output->RFIn.HCS500 works! On Holtek chips this work well for test purposes.